# swift3 IOS google plus login not working

Tags: ios, swift3, google-plus-signin

When I try to integrate the google plus login in swift 3.0, it's not return in the app. So can you please provide the working script code.

In the swift 2.0 and previous versions this google plus login is working. May be google need to update the swift 3.0 code snippet.

Thanks,
lakshman

Comment: You can't just expect people to provide you with code snippets so as you may add it directly to your project. Provide your current code and you'll be helped.

Comment: @Emil David,
I added the script to redirect the app. But it is not redirecting properly. Only i face this issue on swift3.0 only. Below verison's it is working fine.

Comment: update your question with the respective code

Comment: When, i try to migrate the Firebase. google login is working fine. I follow the below video url and doing. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=83EXULT480Q

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/google-ios

Comment: So is your problem resolved then?

Comment: @Emil David, the issue is resolved, when we use the Firebase SDK. Current google provide SDK is not working.